# getResources() in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android

When I try to use `getResources().getDrawable(icons[position])` it says "can't resolve method getResources()", giving the options to create a getter, create property or create method.

Why can't I invoke `getResources()` from this class?

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;



    public class MeinPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> fragments; 
        private CharSequence Titles[];

        int icons [] = {R.drawable.ic_info, R.drawable.ic_home,         R.drawable.ic_settings};
    Drawable drawable;

    public MeinPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments,       CharSequence[] titles) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.Titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);

        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: use context in order to run that function

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`getResources()` is a method of class Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()), but you're in a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), which doesn't extend Context.

A possible solution (and the best, in my opinion) is passing a Context in your adapter's constructor:

```
private Context context;

public MeinPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments,       CharSequence[] titles, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.Titles = titles;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);

    return Titles[position];
}
```

Since you're making an instance of your adapter in an Activity, you can pass `this` when creating your adapter:

```
MeinPageAdapter adapter = new MeinPageAdapter(/* your other params*/, this);
```

Comment: This could potentially leak memory if an Activity is passed in as the context parameter, using context.getApplicationContext() will help avoid this